# ¿Cómo envio una variable desde JavaScript hacia PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, onclick

tengo un boton el cual ejecuta una funcion de javascript al hacer click y pasa un parametro (n), el codigo JS es:

```
<script>

 function myuser(n){

        var user = n

    }

</script>
```

y el código del botón es el siguiente (nótese que esta escrito en PHP y por eso el parámetro se pasa de esa manera, con las barras y demas. Eso funciona perfecto ya que desde el código JS puedo imprimir perfectamente este parámetro pasado.

```
echo '<button onclick="myuser(\''.$us.'\')"></button>';
```

Yo una vez obtenida esta variable, lo que quiero hacer ahora es, en la misma función poder pasar esa variable hacia un archivo php y a la vez redirigirme a el para poder imprimir esa variable, estuve investigando un poco pero nada me dio resultado, entiendo que es algo confuso por el hecho de que ambos lenguajes funcionan de distintas maneras pero confio en que hay forma de hacerlo, si me pueden dar una mano seria genial! gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pasar variables desde JavaScript a PHP es algo complejo, ya que cuando Javascript se ejecuta en el cliente, PHP se ejecutó mucho tiempo antes en el servidor.

La manera usual de hacerlo es recargar la página pasando las variables como parámetros para que PHP pueda verlas.

Podemos hacerlo empleando el método GET, pasando las variables en la URL como parámetros, de tal manera que PHP podrá verlas a través del objeto $_GET.

Si en vez del método GET usamos el método POST, las variables no se verán en la URL y PHP podrá acceder a ellas mediante el objeto $_POST.

Para recargar la página usaremos la propiedad `window.location.href` en JavaScript.

Veamos un ejemplo de cómo pasar variables de JavaScript a PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javascript_to_php() {
    var jsVar1 = "Hello";
    var jsVar2 = "World";
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "?w1=" + jsVar1 + "&w2=" + jsVar2;
}
</script>
 
<?php
// comprobar si tenemos los parametros w1 y w2 en la URL
if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"])) {
    // asignar w1 y w2 a dos variables
    $phpVar1 = $_GET["w1"];
    $phpVar2 = $_GET["w2"];
 
    // mostrar $phpVar1 y $phpVar2
    echo "<p>Parameters: " . $phpVar1 . " " . $phpVar1 . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
}
?>
```

Fuente: [http://www.estrellateyarde.org/manual-de-javascript/manual-de-javascript-pasar-variables-desde-javascript-a-php-y-viceversa#:~:text=De%20JavaScript%20a%20PHP,-Pasar%20variables%20desde&text=Podemos%20hacerlo%20empleando%20el%20m%C3%A9todo,mediante%20el%20objeto%20%24_POST%20.](http://www.estrellateyarde.org/manual-de-javascript/manual-de-javascript-pasar-variables-desde-javascript-a-php-y-viceversa#:%7E:text=De%20JavaScript%20a%20PHP,-Pasar%20variables%20desde&text=Podemos%20hacerlo%20empleando%20el%20m%C3%A9todo,mediante%20el%20objeto%20%24_POST%20.)

Comment: Muchas gracias! me funciono a la perfección, había probado con eso antes pero no había solucionado el tema de que me redireccione a la otra pagina, gracias!

Comment: @GonzaloRamirez Excelente! Marca la respuesta como correcta así le sirve a otros en la comunidad con duda similar!